# How to remove SSL certificate from Load balancer on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

We have 3 load balancers on GCP: Dev, Staging and Production.

Our SSL certificate expired, so it was time to replace it. I went to:

*Network services > Load balancing > Load balancers > Edit > Frontend configuration*

and added new certificate. It worked perfectly for Staging and Production.

Dev was working for 5-10 minutes, and after that old certificate was re-applied automatically. I decided to delete the old certificate (if it is not there, it cannot be applied). It worked for 10 minutes and miraculously GCP restored deleted certificate and re-applied it to Dev.

Tried it a few times with the same result.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you share more details of the configuration you are using:
1. What type of Backend Service are you using, with this LB? Is there a GKE cluster used in this configuration?  
2. When you refer to steps Network services,> Load balancing > Load balancers > Edit > Frontend configuration can you mention the specific Load Balancer you are using?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the certificate with the `gcloud` [command](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#delete-ssl-cert-resource)? The behaviour you are experiencing might be an issue related to the UI.

Answer (score 6):

Visit the certificates list in the advanced load-balancing menu, and delete the certificates you want to:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/sslCertificates/list?project=[project_name]`

Comment: As of 2023, this view has moved to: `https://console.cloud.google.com/security/ccm/list/lbCertificates?project=[project_name]`

Answer (score 5):

Because target proxy also using same SSL certificate. Update the target proxy with another SSL certificate, after that  you can delete SSL certificate from load balancer.

Go to cloud sdk shell or cloud shell on browser and run the below command on exact project

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies update PROXY_NAME --ssl-certificates=SSL_CERTIFIFCATE
```

if you don't know the target proxy name use the command below

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies list
```

replace `PROXY_NAME` & `SSL_CERTIFIFCATE`  with exact names

you will get an output like below

```
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-id/global/targetHttpsProxies/target-proxy-name].
```

Now use the below command to delete old SSL certificate from LB.

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete CERTIFICATE_NAME \
    --global
```

replace `CERTIFICATE_NAME` with exact name.